# Invalid Cast Exception for Linq JOIN on Strongly typed Dataset Tables

Tags: c#, linq, exception, dataset

Have browsed a few similar questions, but couldn't apply them to this. I'm performing a Linq query on a strongly typed dataset:

```
query = From g In dbDS.gi_game
        Join o In dbDS.gi_organisation
        On g.DeveloperID Equals o.ID
        Select o
```

`g.DeveloperID` and `o.ID` are both strings. `g.DeveloperID` holds the `gi_organisation.ID`

The dataset is filled from a mysql database via table adpaters.

This returns an exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type '<JoinIterator>d__38`4[OmniGameZzap.gameinfozDataSet+gi_gameRow,OmniGameZzap.gameinfozDataSet+gi_organisationRow,System.String,OmniGameZzap.gameinfozDataSet+gi_organisationRow]' to type 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection`1[OmniGameZzap.gameinfozDataSet+gi_gameRow]'.'
```

What's occurring?

Comment: You'll need to use FirstOrDefault or similar

Comment: @mb14 Thanks for the response. Where? Could you provide a code example?

Comment: yeah, definitely. I assume your "query" expects a single item for a result but when you do SELECT, that always returns an IEnumerable, hence your error. So, (From g In dbDS.gi_game Join o In dbDS.gi_organisation On g.DeveloperID Equals o.ID Select o).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Ah no. It's used as in the SQL `Join` statement which retrieves all rows in game and organisation which are matched via the foreign/primary keys (in this case `g.DeveloperID` and `o.ID`). So not a single row. I did try your code to see what it did. It wouldn't compile due to casting a collection into a single.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell you how to resolve the problem, because I am not firm enough with expressive LINQ.

But from the exception message you provided, I would guess the issue lies in the `Select o` line.

Comment: Agreed - it does seem to centre around the Select statement, but cannot for the life of me figure out what I'm meant to put here!

Answer (score 0):

Dammit. The perils of ommiting surrounding code. Transpires, it was preceeding code that was throwing a spanner in the works. Full original code:

```
Dim query = From g In dbDS.gi_game Where g.SystemID = SystemID Select g
query.CopyToDataTable(ds.gi_game, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges)

query = From g In dbDS.gi_game
        Join o In dbDS.gi_organisation On g.DeveloperID Equals o.ID
        Select o
```

Working code:

```
Dim query = From g In dbDS.gi_game Where g.SystemID = SystemID Select g
query.CopyToDataTable(ds.gi_game, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges)

Dim orgs = From g In dbDS.gi_game
            Join o In dbDS.gi_organisation On g.DeveloperID Equals o.ID
            Select o
```

Looks like query got typed to a datatable or something.